# Custom Bins with Bokeh plot python?

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to give Bins as a custom bins in Bokeh with histogram plots ,

so for example instead of 

`hist = Histogram(df, values='hp', color='cyl',
                 title="HP Distribution by Cylinder Count", legend='top_right' , bins = 20)`

I want bins to be a list

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh 0.11.1 this is not possible but this is supposed to be a feature soon

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/4250